# Stored Procedure - loop through results without cursor

Tags: sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, resultset

Everywhere I look I see that in order to loop through results you have to use a cursor and in the same post someone saying cursors are bad don't use them (which has always been my philosophy) but now I am stuck.  I need to loop through a result set!

Here's the situation.  I need to come up with a list of ProductIDs that have 2 different statuses set to a specific value.  I start the stored procedure, run the query that finds my products that meet the criteria.
So, now I have a list of ProductIDs that I need to run through my validation process:

16050

16052

41817

48255

Now I need for each of those products (there may be 1 there may be 1000, i don't know) to check a whole list of conditions:
Is a specific field = 'SIMPLE'? if so, perform a bunch of other queries and make sure everything is good
If it is not 'SIMPLE' then run a whole other set of queries and make sure that information is all good.

Is another field = 'YES'? if so, perform a bunch of other queries, if it is not, then do other queries.

Is a cursor what I need to use?  Is there some other way to do what I need that I just am not seeing?

Thanks,
Leslie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a WHILE loop that I can pass each ProductID into a series of checks!!

```
declare @counter int
declare @productKey varchar(20)

SET @counter = (select COUNT(*) from ##Magento)

while (1=1) 
begin
SET @productKey = (select top 1 ProductKey from ##Magento)
print @productKey;
delete from ##Magento Where ProductKey = @productKey
SET @counter-=1;
  IF (@counter=0) BREAK;

end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing the specifics of your process, but one approach is to create a function that performs your logic and call that.

eg:

```
delete from yourtable
where productid in (select ProductID from FilteredProducts)
and dbo.ShouldBeDeletedFunction(ProductID) = 1
```

In general, cursors are bad, but there are always exceptions.  Try to avoid them by thinking in terms of sets, rather than the attributes of an individual record.